# From list to Excel on Talend

Tags: java, etl, talend

I have a tJavaFlex on Talend which produces a list of values ​​and I would like to write these values ​​in an Excel file.

Here is my job :

[image]

My tJavaFlex code is:

```
// start part of your Java code
java.util.ArrayList<row5Struct> list = new java.util.ArrayList<row5Struct>() ; 

// here is the main part of the component,
// a piece of code executed in the row
// loop
row5Struct row_new = new row5Struct();

row_new.date = row5.getDate();
row_new.id = row5.getId();
row_new.total = row5.getTotal();

list.add(row_new) ;

// end of the component, outside/closing the loop
int n = 1 ;
for(int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++)
{
     // an algorithm that modifies the list and deletes some rows
}
```

How can I send values from a list on tJavaFlex to an Excel file ?

If there is another way to retrieve SQL data by deleting and modifying some lines I am also taker.

Comment: And what is your question? You posted some sort of requirement, and some code, but what is your question?

Comment: "I would like to write these values ​​in an Excel file." How can I proceed ?

Comment: @dev_bi https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, I’m sorry I misworded my question

Comment: It is not about wording, you are not facing a problem. You are asking for a solution from scratch, you have done no research on the issue and you have tried to implement nothing. This is not the point of stackoverflow, it is to help you with technical problems that you are facing, not to give you a full solution to your work/tickets.

Comment: @Dimitris I’ve been researching my problem for 3 days and trying to go through several methods but I still can’t. Stackoverflow was my last option.

Comment: Post the methods that you tried, what errors you had while trying them. Then people can help you solve your issues

Comment: Use a global variable as  globalMap.put("list", yourlist ) . then use a tfixedFlowinput that have a column  type list in the value  globalMap.get("list") . then linhe tfixedFlowinput 
 with tfileoutputdelimited

Comment: or after tjavaflex -> tsetglobalvar  then link tfixedFlowinput with tfileoutputdelimited  on other subjob

Comment: what kind of list are you creating ? You could use a tAggregateRow with "list" type if you just have a list of string elements

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa I put 'for( row5Struct elem: list)
{
       globalMap.put("date", elem.getNb_ko_date());
 globalMap.put("hour", elem.getNb_ko_hour());
}
' at the end of my tJavaFlex, and I put (tfixedFlowinput -> tfileoutputdelimited) in another subjob.

This only gives me the first line in my excel.

Comment: @Corentin It's a list of objects with different types of variables in each object. Each "object" is supposed to represent a line on excel.

Comment: if you print in the tjavaflex in the for loop the global variable and see

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa It displays all the data, but the "globalMap.put" takes only the last value in tJavaFlex loop.